# Joomla:: Is it safe to store plaintext passwords in session for authentication bridge

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm working on a plugin and component for Joomla 3+, and they will be used to interface with an API that requires the plaintext password to be passed via an HTTPS REST URL.  I don't want the users to log on multiple times, so I'm wondering if I can (**SAFELY**) store their passwords in a plain text session.

Basically like this...

**Authentication Plugin:**

```
function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response) {
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('plainpassword', $credentials['password']);
.....
}
```

**Component model:**

```
public function getItems() {
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$plainpassword = $session->get('plainpassword');
.....
}
```

I could randomize the session name, but is there anything else I should be aware of?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only if you don't care if a total stranger can use it. 
Are you saying you want to use the Joomla password? Absolutely not.
If you are logging in somewhere else why not share a session and indicate that the user is authenticated rather than resend the password each time? I'm not being mean in saying this, you need to really study up on authentication and authorization if you are going to do something like this. Keep in mind that your users are probably using the same password elsewhere.

Comment: Because I don't have control over the API.  As I stated, it's an HTTPS REST URL that requires the password to be sent.  This is their only method for user authentication.  

The username, password, and ip address are all sent through the URL, and an authorization token is received.  From there I use the token in a second URL to direct the user to their control panel.

Comment: Based on my response, if you have any better idea's I'd be happy to study up on them. :)

Comment: OK, here's a better idea.  How about I use an encrypt / decrypt pair of methods to store an encrypted version of the password in session, and then decrypt it when I need it?

Comment: And this is unique for each logged in user?  What I would do is make a joomla plugin that uses the Joomla authentication event so also login to the control panel of your other application. Then store whatever they need.   I take it from this that you are going to be using a shared uname/pass right?   I doubt very much that their api is expecting you to reauthenticate on every pageload, it wants you do do it once and then save a cookie probably.  If it is https you don't have to worry about sniffing on the wire which is a good thing anyway.

Comment: That's a really good idea in theory, but I'm very curious how something like that would be implemented.  It sounds almost like a reverse man-in-the-middle attack.  How would I generate an authentication on the server, and then in silently pass the cookies to the client computer?

The API allows me to send credentials through to get a temporary token (120 seconds), but ultimately the authentication happens when the client uses the generated token to access the other website.

Maybe I haven't explained the situation well enough.

Comment: Presumably you are starting a session on the other application since you reference going to the control panel ("rom there I use the token in a second URL to direct the user to their control panel.").  I would assume that once the client is authenticated the other application is generating a session and probably storing a cookie.   In other words you pass the u/p once, at the same time as you do for joomla. You need to read about joomla events and authentication.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm having a hard time accepting it as a viable solution. The control panel is housed on another server, shown as a subdomain to my site.  So if I generate a token/session at user login, that means opening the subdomain in a separate window at login....whether the user wants it or not.

Comment: Because it destroys the session when the tab is closed? Then you are going to have to use the hashed joomla password or require reauthentication.   I haven't thought this out completely but you could also store something in a new table in the database with a two way encrypted password and store the encryption key somewhere ... you could look at JKeychain and extend it to store in the database and store a separate keychain for each user possibly.  Also you could go look at jfusion and how they manage this kind of thing.

Comment: I ended up using mcrypt_encrypt/mcrypt_decrypt, and I think this will be sufficient.

Comment: But not in a session or cookie right? YOu are storing it in a table that requires a password (something that can be gotten by anyone who spots an unattended computer with logged in session. And you're not using the same password as for joomla right? If you generate a random string as the 2nd application's password for each user and then encrypt it and store the encrypted string in a database table and you check to make sure there in authenticated joomla session that is the only way to login you might be somewhat okay. I would destroy and recreate the password on each authentication.

Comment: I don't have any control over the second application.  It requires a real password to access it, so I have to store the plaintext password (yes, Joomla's password) somewhere.  I can store it in the database temporarily during auth, but your scenario above about a logged in user will still happen.  The point of this application is so that the user will not need to log onto multiple applications distinctly, and so I'm using token generation methods to create an authenticated session.

Comment: So what you do is store a random string as the password in a database table and use that to login. Do not use the joomla password as that is dangerous and deceptive to your users since you have promised them implicitly that their passwords will be safe but you are proposing to put them at serious risk.  If you have a client you are proposing to put your client at serious risk.  What you need to do instead if you insist on storing a password with two way encryption is to make a random password and store it in the database with the user id and then use that to login.

Comment: If you are generating tokens use those. There are lots of excellent solutions for single sign on but none of them involve exposing people's passwords to hackers or even to their snooping family members.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if I used a random password then I would need to change the users password at the second site every time they log in.  This would generate a "Your password was changed" email to the user each time, and users would not be able to access both systems with a single password.

Comment: No you would not, though it would definitely be a good idea to do so.  If you are sying you also want them to be able to directly enter app2 not via joomla that is changing the whole problem.  You should just go look at jfusion and do what they do rather than playing around putting users and your site at risk.  You have not said what research you have done at all, but you need to read a lot before you try this.

Comment: OK, am I misunderstanding your statement? How would I use a random password in the API, without changing the user password in app2?

Comment: How are you getting the passwords into the database in app2? (Not how are users logging in, how are you actually getting the passwords into the database).

Comment: The users already exist in app2, and so I built a Joomla plugin to authenticate against the app2 API.

Comment: I don't have access to the app2 database or the passwords, I can only use the API methods allowed.

Comment: If you don't know the names or passwords in the app2 database what makes you think that the joomla names and passwords will allow them in?

Comment: Because the API allows me to generate a token (similarly to OAuth) for authentication by passing the username, password, and IP address.  I'm using this method in a Joomla auth plugin to create the login session.

Comment: You really need to create a new question about this issue (since hte answer to your original question was no) and explain the flow exactly because you are contradicting yourself in now saying that you don't know the names and passwords in app2.

Comment: I don't think I'm contradicting myself - I know my own username and password, but I don't know anyone else.... nor should I know theirs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62300/discussion-between-james-shaver-and-elin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elin suggested, I ended up saving the encrypted password to a temporary table.